# Run-time error '91' when I open excel file on different location - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I read an excel file in order to read each cell of a selection. I run my program and everything works. But if then I move the excel file to another location and run my program then I get the **run-time error message '91' Object variable or with block variable not set**

```
Public Function ReadDataFromCloseFile(filepathExcel As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Hide the files during the microseconds while they're open.

    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim name As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim data As String
    
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(filepathExcel)
                        
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim NumDynavia As Variant

    Set myrange = src.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("G8:G501")
```

And he debugger stop at the last line of this piece of code (set myrange).

When I checked the variable :

- filepathExcel has the good path
- But set myrange is **empty**

Comment: Where is ```filepathExcel``` set? When you move the file, how does the variable get updated? Does the file open after it's moved?

Comment: I use an openDialog window (I checked, the variable filepathExcel is weel updated but myrange is empty. At the end I use src.close and set src = Nothing

Comment: If the workbook is already open, calling `Workbooks.Open` on it can cause issues (my guess as to the problem).

Comment: the workbook is closed, I use just this method to read it and close it at the end... I'm missing something ^^'

Comment: It's not clear *what* and *at which point* you are moving to another location. Error 91 on that specific line can only occur when `src` is `Nothing`, which, in turn, can only occur if the code you have shown is not in fact the code you are actually running. If we assume that you may be misreporting the location of the error, then see if the other Excel file has a `Workbook_Open` handler, and what it does.